# JMS Unable to resolve QueueConnectionFactory

Tags: queue, jms, weblogic12c

volks!

I have a problem. I want to read some messages from Weblogic 12c. This code is currently working with another server, which wasn't configured by me. So the problem may be in configuration of server.

The problem is when I use code:

```
public final static String JNDI_FACTORY="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";
public final static String JMS_FACTORY="QCF";
public final static String QUEUE="dizzyworldQueue";
public final static String USER_NAME="weblogic";
public final static String USER_PASSWORD="Welcome1";
public final static String URL="t3://localhost:8001";

private static InitialContext getInitialContext(String url) throws NamingException
{
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, USER_NAME);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, USER_PASSWORD);
    return new InitialContext(env);
}


    qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
    qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection(); // here it falls
```

The error is:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'QCF'. Resolved '' [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'QCF'. Resolved '']; remaining name 'QCF'

I have Queue and QueueConnection factory on my server. What can be the rison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says that there is no connection factory bound in your naming service (JNDI) with the name "QCF".

So you have to configure your application server to offer the queue connection factory through JNDI.

If that is already the case, you have to change that name in your client code to match the name in JNDI.

You have to add the connection factory and the queue in the admin console.

Look for Services - JMS modules. Possibly add a JMS module, and add a connection factory and queue.

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/JMSServiceWLS/JMSServiceWLS.html), it shows the steps to configure it.

Comment: Great Tutorial. I did thit steps twice, but it was a small difference beetwen them. Thank you!

Comment: @NarendraJaggi That tutorial has gone, have a look at the new one.